# How to convert a single object to a boost::any_range?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-range, boost-iterators

I'm trying to create and return a boost:any_range that contains only one object (I don't know if that's the core problem) but I get the following errors:

- error C2893: Failed to specialize function template
  'range_iterator<C,void>::type boost::range_adl_barrier::begin(T &)'
- note: With the following template arguments:
- note: 'T=const WrappedRange'
- error C2672: 'end': no matching overloaded function    found
- error C2893: Failed to specialize function template
  'range_iterator<C,void>::type boost::range_adl_barrier::end(T &)'
- note: With the following template arguments: note: 'T=const
  WrappedRange'

Below you can find the relevant code snippets:

1. That's the function I want to call and which fails during compiling:

```
const HandleRange BasicCollection::GetPartHandles() const
{
    return HandleRange
    //return -> also tried this
    {
        Handle(GenericHandleManager::CreatePartHandleValue(GenericHandleManager::GetPartIdx(_collectionHandle)))
    };
}
```

Somehow this works, but that's not really clean:

```
const HandleRange BasicCollection::GetPartHandles() const
{
    auto container = { _collectionHandle };

    return container | boost::adaptors::transformed([collectionHandle = _collectionHandle](const auto & index_value)
    {
        return HandleRange::value_type
        {
            Handle(GenericHandleManager::CreatePartHandleValue(GenericHandleManager::GetPartIdx(collectionHandle)))
        };
    });
}
```

2. That's the HandleRange type that shall be returned:

```
/**
 * Defines an alias representing a boost range for handles.
 */
 using HandleRange = boost::any_range<Handle, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const Handle>;
```

3. The used Handle object:

```
class Handle
{
public:
     /**
      * Construct a handle from a handle value.
      * @param    value   The handle's value.
      */
      inline explicit Handle(int_fast64_t value) noexcept : _value(value)
      {
      }
...
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Somehow this works, but that's not really clean

That should not compile without diagnostics, as `auto` is deduced as `std::initializer_list<Handle>`.

That approach invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the initializer list doesn't exist after returning.

### Solutions

The `any_range` should be able to return an iterator range.

Pointers are iterators.

Any single object `o` can be seen as a range `[&o, &o + 1)`. That's a valid iterator range.

Combining these would already be a solution **if** `GenericHandleManager::CreatePartHandleValue(...)` returns a reference:

```
const HandleRange BasicCollection::GetPartHandles() const {
    Handle& h =
      GenericHandleManager::CreatePartHandleValue(
          GenericHandleManager::GetPartIdx(_collectionHandle));
    return boost::make_iterator_range(&h, &h + 1));
}
```

### Singleton Ranges

If it returns a temporary, though, you'll need to make that "a range":

```
template <typename T>
struct SingletonRange : boost::iterator_range<T*> {
    T val;
    SingletonRange(T val)
      : boost::iterator_range<T*>(std::addressof(val), std::addressof(val) + 1),
        val(std::move(val))
    { }
};
```

Now you can safely¹ write (even though `CreatePartHandleValue` returns a temporary):

```
HandleRange BasicCollection::GetPartHandles() const {
    Handle h =
        GenericHandleManager::CreatePartHandleValue(
            GenericHandleManager::GetPartIdx(_collectionHandle));

    return SingletonRange<Handle> {h};
}
```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf49d7f8dd0bd624)**

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct SingletonRange : boost::iterator_range<T*> {
    T val;
    SingletonRange(T val)
      : boost::iterator_range<T*>(std::addressof(val), std::addressof(val) + 1),
        val(std::move(val))
    { }
};

struct Handle{};
struct GenericHandleManager {
    static int GetPartIdx(Handle)            { return 42; }
    static Handle CreatePartHandleValue(int) { return {}; }
};

#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>
using HandleRange = boost::any_range<Handle, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const Handle>;

struct BasicCollection {
    HandleRange GetPartHandles() const;
  private:
    Handle _collectionHandle;
};

HandleRange BasicCollection::GetPartHandles() const {
    Handle h =
        GenericHandleManager::CreatePartHandleValue(
            GenericHandleManager::GetPartIdx(_collectionHandle));

    return SingletonRange<Handle> {h};
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    BasicCollection coll;
    for (Handle h : coll.GetPartHandles()) {
        std::cout << "Handle in loop\n";

        boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning(h);
    }
}
```

> Keep in mind that copying that range is as expensive as copying an
> `iterator_range<Handle*>` plus copying the `Handle` itself. I'm
> assuming the Handle is lightweight (as usual for handles)

Prints

```
Handle in loop
```

---

¹ as long as you make sure you don't use any iterators from the SingletonRange after the lifetime of the range. This is a common C++ pattern though