# Problems with returning references to local variables...?

Tags: c++, vector, boost, iterator, local-variables

There is a complaint that the following function doesn't work because it returns "pointers/iterators to local variables". Is this complaint correct? I can't see this problem...

```
const Range dummy::foo() const
{
    std::vector<Handle> _handles;
    _handles.reserve(_collection.size());

    for (const auto& pair: _collection)
    {
        _handles.push_back(pair.first);
    }

    return _handles;
}
```

Return type:

```
using Range = boost::any_range<Handle, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const Handle>;
```

Thanks for explanations and suggested solutions!

Comment: What is type of `Range` ?

Comment: You are never allowed to return a reference to a function local variable.  All function loval variables are destroyed once the function returns leaving any reference to them dangling.

Comment: *There is a complaint that the following function doesn't work* -- Who made the complaint?  C++ has something called value-semantics, and from all looks of it, you are returning a value, not a pointer, iterator, or reference.

Comment: My guess would be that `boost::any_range` just holds an iterator pair as opposed to a copy of the entire vector, and those iterators become invalid when the function returns.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani sorry. I added it.

Comment: @NathanOliver and how could I change my code? Should I define _handles globally?

Comment: @PythonLinski What not just return the vector from the function?

Comment: Change `const Range dummy::foo() const` to `std::vector<Handle> dummy::foo() const`

Comment: foo is a function defined in an interface which multiple other classes implements and where the Range is required.

Comment: @PythonLinski If a `Range` can be implcitly created from a `vector` lie you do in your function, then you can still return a vector and the call site will do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this complaint correct?

Yes it is. `_handles` is an automatic variable, and you return a range referring to it. Ranges are basically abstractions over pairs of iterator + sentinel. The returned range will be invalid outside the function.

> And how can I solve this

A correct implementation would be to return a transforming adaptor range. Possibly something along the lines of:

```
return _collection | boost::adaptors::map_keys;
```

Comment: And how can I solve this if the Range as return type is required?

Comment: Minor nit: the oneliner `return _collection | boost::adaptors::map_keys;` is more direct. Also, some [historical context in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585222/85371)

Comment: @sehe Thanks. I've edited the answer. I did guess that the more specific adaptor might already exist in Boost, but couldn't find it in a minute of searching.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I predicted this a month ago in my answer here:  [How to convert a single object to a boost::any_range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238116/how-to-convert-a-single-object-to-a-boostany-range/65238725#65238725)

The problem is much the same as your initializer_list:

> That approach invokes Undefined Behaviour because the initializer list doesn't exist after returning.

Here, the same applies to the vector.

Instead of the iterator-wrapping range you can of course simply return the vector itself. Otherwise you could emploiy the exact same techniques I used in that other answer where I constructed a singleton range (with value-semantics).